# When is Active Directory Auto Detected

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, account-management

I'm building an application that will authenticate users via Active Directory. Nothing major, not adding or editing users, just validating credentials. I found many posts on this - some using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (.NET 3.5 and above) or using LDAP DirectoryEntry...

I'm trying to figure out if I have to specify the AD server URL? When I test, I do not need to specify anything?

1. When is the AD server auto detected? When do I need to specify a URL?
2. Is there a call I can make to get the auto detected AD server URL?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a domain `PrincipalContext` or `DirectoryContext` without specifying a domain or path, the current context is used. i.e. the account the code is executing under. If the code is executing under an account not in a domain an exception will be thrown. This applies weather running in a windows forms app or in a service.

To validate credentials against a domain all you need to do is:

```
public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    using (var principalcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        return principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
}
```

However, this is not the best way to do this for many reasons. For example, `ValidateCredentials` can return true even if the user cannot log in due to expired passwords etc. Secondly, there is a much easier way to use active directory single sign-on for desktop applications:

```
var currentUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

This returns the principal for the current user, there's no need to re-authenticate, windows already did that, and therefore you already know the user is valid.

Comment: What are the many reasons? I do not only want to do the current user, so UserPrincipal.Current will not work. I will allow my user to log in as a different user too. What do you recommend?

Comment: How about a diff domain under the same AD? Would this work? PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, otherDomainName);

Comment: @MikeTurner Then you can use the 1st code example in my answer as long as the current user is part of the domain, if not then specify a domain, username and password to use for authentication checking.

Comment: @SOS Yes that will work fine. If a trust is in place then the domain still isn't needed though if the username you are checking includes domain information.

Comment: @Ashigore What are the other reasons that it is best not to do this?